# Campaign Workflow

Tags: salesforce, dataflow, salesforce-lightning

I'm hoping someone has done this before but I keep running into walls with trying Flows and/or Process Builder.

When I create a campaign in Salesforce, I'd like the following to happen:

- **Contact** - if the Contact ID is associated with a Campaign Member ID - make a checkbox on the contact record true
- **Campaign** - if the campaign is between certain date ranges - make the status Planned, In Progress, Completed, etc.

The issue I'm finding is that there is 1 Contact Record with multiple associated Campaign Member ID's & Campaign Id's.

Any thoughts of some workarounds?

Comment: This Campaign data model and flow doesn't make sense. CampaignMember is a junction object between Contact (or Lead) and Campaign. It's not possible for a CampaignMember to exist at the point in time the parent Campaign is created, and you'll generally want more sophisticated criteria if you want to roll up Campaign Member details to the Contact level _because_ it is one to many.

Comment: Thanks.  I am able to update the Campaign status, correctly but not the Contact record.  Any ideas on how I can change the Contact checkbox on whether there is an active campaign associated with that record?

Comment: I would suggest using [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). There is no OOTB tool that does so.